# Create custom color theme with semantic highlighting support in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently tried out the JetBrains Fleet text editor and I loved its theme, but because it's so laggy and unresponsive I can't use. So I decided to port the theme to VS Code. I have 0 experience with creating color themes for VS Code.

To change the colors I opened `settings.json` and edited `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations`. This worked very well and I have a 1:1 copy of the theme, but there are multiple problems. The first one is that I want it to be an extension, because I am overwriting the default Modern Dark theme it always takes about 5 seconds before the changes happen. It also only works with rust-analyzer.

This got me wondering how does the default Modern Dark theme in VS Code work? How do all the colors work for all languages? And how can I change them, or create my own version of it with my own colors?

I tried creating a theme using yeoman but when generating the theme it never saves the semantic tokens. I also tried looking into `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/themes-default` but the default theme is just the colors of the windows and not the code. Thanks for any help.

Comment: read the extension writing doc pages for themes